# String addition assignment in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a loop with a condition, based on which I decide whether I should append something to existing string or not.
In Python, it should look like (this is dummy code, just to show the idea):

```
result_str = ''
for item in range(5):
  if item % 2 == 0:
    result_str += str(item)

print(result_str)
```

Output: `024`

So the question is: how can I perform addition assignment on strings (`+=`) in lisp?

Comment: With another library, you have `str:concat`: https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str/ See also https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String concatenation relies on the more general [`CONCATENATE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_concat.htm) function:

```
(concatenate 'string "a" "b")
=> "ab"
```

Since it considered verbose by some, you can find libraries that implement shorter versions:

```
(ql:quickload :rutils)
(import 'rutils:strcat)
```

And then:

```
(strcat "a" "b")
```

In order to assign and grow a string, you need to use `SETF` with an existing variable.

```
(let ((string ""))
  (dotimes (i 5)
    (when (evenp i)
      (setf string (strcat string (princ-to-string i)))))
  string)
```

A more idiomatic way in Lisp is to avoid string concatenation, but print in a stream which writes into a buffer.

```
(with-output-to-string (stream)
  ;; now, stream is bound to an output stream 
  ;; that writes into a string. The whole form 
  ;; returns that string.
  (loop
     for i from 0 below 5 by 2
     do (princ i stream)))
 => "024"
```

Here above, `stream` is just the symbol used for naming the stream, you could use any other one, including `*standard-output*`, the special variable that represents current output stream. Doing so would make the enclosed code redirect its standard output to the string stream.

An alternative way to build the intermediate list is the following, where `iota` is a small utility in the [alexandria](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/alexandria/alexandria) library:

```
(delete-if #'oddp (alexandria:iota 5))
=> (0 2 4)
```

In order to produce a string, you can also use [`FORMAT`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_format.htm), which has a directive that can iterate over lists:

```
(format nil "~{~a~}" '(0 2 4))
=> "024"
```

The `nil` stream destination represents a string destination, meaning `(format nil ...)` returns a string. Each directive starts with a tilde character (`~`), `~{` and `~}` enclose an iteration directive; inside that block, `~a` prints the value "aesthetically" (not readably).